# jQuery using Sortable with dynamically added elements (live refresh)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, refresh, live, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a `<form id="#form">` that have a `<span class="con">` and inside the span i have many divs that needs to be sortable.

```
<form id="form">
    <span class="con">
        <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</div>
        <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</div>
        ... 
    </span>
</form>
```

I'm using the sortable function to make div Sortable.

```
$("span").sortable({
    connectWith: ".con"
}).disableSelection();
```

I'm dynamically adding  with divs inside. But sortable is not recognizing  newly added spans. I know there's a `refresh` option for sortable that is supposed to work like `live()` and reognize newly added content, but i don't see how i can use it with this example.

**Check http://jsfiddle.net/mRyVp/8/**. Click on the button to add more spans with divs inside. You will see that you can sort div that were initially in DOM but not newly added ones.

Comment: it seems that you have multiple sortable `<span>`, that certainly will not work as a single group.

Comment: @experimentx, yes you can connect multiple spans. Check example here http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-update. Since spans are dynamically added, it doesn't work, otherwise if all were initially in DOM it will work.

Comment: @Hussein it seems that you are right, i will have a look the code again.

Comment: I thought `refresh` was supposed to refresh dynamically added content but it's not working `$('span').sortable('refresh')`

Comment: shouldn't your `<span>` be a `<div>`? or your `<div>`s be `<span>`s ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you have `class="connectedSortable"` in

```
<span class="connectedSortable">
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</div>
    ... 
</span>
```

And `connectWith: ".con"` in

```
$("span").sortable({
    connectWith: ".con"
}).disableSelection();
```

Adding `con` class to original div will just be fine. Update [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mRyVp/5/).

Comment: Thanks experiment +1. but this is a little awkward. You are using sortable twice, one within the click function and one outside. We should only use it once and then make use of the refresh option.

Comment: @Pikie well, i check it again.

Comment: @Pinkie well, the newly created `<span>` does not have `sortable` function associated with it, so we have to register it again(after its creation) else it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight">Item '+($('.con div').length+1)+'</div>');
    x.appendTo('#form .con')
});

$("span").sortable({
    connectWith: ".con"
}).disableSelection();
```

When you click over 'add another option', the script will add new sortable 'Item' into the list

Answer (score 0):

Change Button Click event as given below, and it works. No other changes are required. 
I tried in jfiddler and it worked. Newly added items becomes part of list and are sortable as well.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var x = $('<div>aaaaaaaaa</div>');
    x.appendTo('#form .con')
});
```

I defined x as  element and further x is appenedTo ".con" class inside #form.

The screen-shot of this updated example is shown below:

[image]